# SSIS foreach file enumerator Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, business-intelligence, ssis

When I run my SSIS package manually thru BIDS , it runs without any problem. As soon as I get SQL agent to run the package I get an error. Server is 32 - bit and SSIS packages are set to run on 32- but and SQL Job agent is also set to run on 32 bit. Can someone please help me to decrypt the error.

`Code: 0xC0010018  Description: Error loading value "<DTS:ForEachEnumerator xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts">  <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">{BF37E898-52FF-4A7C-8B23-3DD38D8254EE}</DTS:Property>  <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{3f53d0f5-48c0-4084-b603-497b41170c01}</DTS:Property>  <DTS:Prope" from node "DTS:ForEachEnumerator".  End Error  Error: 2014-06-18 21:35:37.66     Code: 0xC0010018     Source: {0DBEF258-745D-4EFE-8E17-5DA9DF50D111}      Description: Error loading value <DTS:ForEachEnumerator xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts">  <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">{4E836489-8D8F-41BF-A60D-3A06B2B1CB04}</DTS:Property>  <DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{4E836489-8D8F-41BF-A60D-3A06B2B1CB04}</DTS:Property>  <DTS:Prope" from node "DTS:ForEachEnumerator".  End Error  Error: 2014-06-18 21:35:37.74     Code: 0xC0010021     Source:       Description: Element "{006ec8b0-922a-4fb5-9ed1-7434fbb9d7b3}" does not exist in collection "Executables".  End Error  Error: 2014-06-18 21:35:37.74     Code: 0xC0010018     Source:       Description: Error loading value "<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts" IDREF="{006ec8b0-922a-4fb5-9ed1-7434fbb9d7b3}" DTS:IsFrom="0"/>" from node "DTS:Executable".  End Error  Error: 2014-06-18 21:35:37.74     Code: 0xC0010018     Source:       Description: Error loading value "<DTS:PrecedenceConstraint xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts">  <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Value">0</DTS:Property>  <DTS:Property DTS:Name="EvalOp">2</DTS:Property>  <DTS:Property DTS:Name="LogicalAnd">-1</DTS:Property>  <DTS:Property DTS:Name="Expres" from node "DTS:PrecedenceConstraint".  End Error  Error: 2014-06-18 21:35:37.76     Code: 0xC00220DE     Source: Inspection_Package      Description: Error 0xC0010014 while loading package file "D:\Project\xxxx_Staging_Transformation - Prod\Integration Services Project1\xxxxxxxxx_Inspection_Snapshot.dtsx"`

UPDATE : When I changed the Job timing from 8PM to 6PM , The Package executed successfully.
I wonder this issue has to do with the server performance.

Comment: We need more information to be relevant. What is the package doing? If you run it from the command line, does it work? `dtexec.exe /file "D:\Project\xxxx_Staging_Transformation - Prod\Integration Services Project1\xxxxxxxxx_Inspection_Snapshot.dtsx"`

Comment: No problem running from command line. I have a for each enumerator (File) which reads text files and inserts into Database. It ran without any problem for last 300 days but suddenly stopped after 11th June 2014..No server upgrade at all.

Comment: Is it possible to Enable Package Logging so that you can get more insight about what's causing failure.

Comment: How are you retrieving filenames into foreach collection. Is filename contains any timestamp in it.

Comment: SSIS 2008, you must be using package deployment... are you using configuration files for the package?

Comment: Are you retrieving files from a network share?  If so, does the SSIS account have permissions?

Comment: Yes I am trying to access File form Network share, but when I execute jobs at 8PM I get this error but when I execute jobs at 6PM I don't get any error. And this is what is puzzling me.

Comment: Is the SQL Server on a different host? Run it in BIDS on that computer and see what happens.

Comment: I have no problem running it using BIDS..Only problem when I run the job at 8PM using SQL Server Job Agent by using File Deploymeny but when I moved my job to different time, it had no problem at all.